# Wordpress filtering custom post type taxonomy

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, forms

I've been following this guide: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html#comment-908. I've got a custom post type called "project" and a taxonomy called "producten". What i'm trying to achieve is that the filters categories under the taxonomies get called and the user can filter the posts by using those taxonomies. I did get it working with a dropdown, but what i want are filters. I've created these by using checkboxes which do work, it's just that when i actually try to filter, all posts get shown, no matter which filter i select. The code is used on a random template called test.php.

I feel like there's some really obvious mistake i'm making but i can't seem to figure it out.

The code in test.php:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
            <?php
                if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'producten' ) ) ) :
                    echo '<div class="project-filters button-group-pills text-center" data-toggle="buttons">';
                    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
                        echo '<label class="btn btn-transparent" for="product_' . $term->term_id . '"><input type="checkbox" id="product_' . $term->term_id . '" name="product_' . $term->term_id . '" />' . $term->name . '</label>';
                    endforeach;
                    echo '</div>';
                endif;
            ?>
            <button>Pas filters toe</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
        </form>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function(){

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
    'order' => $_POST['date'], // ASC or DESC
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'producten' ) ) ) :
$all_terms = array();

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    if( isset( $_GET['product_' . $term->term_id ] ) && $_GET['product_' . $term->term_id] == 'on' )
         $all_terms[] = $term->slug;
}

if( count( $all_terms ) > 0 ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'producten',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms'=> $all_terms
        )
    );
}

endif;


$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<div class="row projecten-wrapper">';
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    echo '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 project">';
    echo '<div class="project-wrapper">
                <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">
                <div class="project-header">
                <div class="project-bottom">
                <div class="project-text">';
    echo '<div class="project-title"><span>';
    echo the_title();
    echo '</span>
                </div>
                <div class="project-subtitle"><p>';
    echo  the_excerpt();
    echo  '</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="project-arrow">
                <div class="svg-wrapper">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15.528" height="27.359" viewBox="0 0 15.528 27.359">
                    <g id="Group_5" data-name="Group 5" transform="translate(2568.865 -660.337) rotate(90)">
                        <g id="Group_2" data-name="Group 2" transform="translate(660.337 2553.337)">
                            <rect id="Rectangle_11" data-name="Rectangle 11" width="19.346" height="2.614" rx="1.307" transform="translate(0 13.679) rotate(-45)" fill="#fff"/>
                            <rect id="Rectangle_12" data-name="Rectangle 12" width="19.346" height="2.614" rx="1.307" transform="translate(25.51 15.528) rotate(-135)" fill="#fff"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-wrapper">';

    if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;
    echo    '<div class="layer gradient-1">
                </div>
                <div class="layer">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </div>
                </div>';
            endwhile;
    echo    '</div>';

            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'No posts found';
        endif;

        die();

    }
```

And the jQuery function:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
            $('#response').html(data); // insert data
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: you might edit to show which $_GET -> $_POST you changed, probably here `'order' => $_POST['date'],` // CHANGED FROM $_GET to $_POST, for future clarity. Welcome to SO.

Comment: You should add  your own answer and then accept it (yes, it is not against the rules, happens all the time :) ) and not edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually found the solution after hours of trying. Changing $_GET to $_POST did the trick.**

```
if( isset( $_GET['product_' . $term->term_id ] ) && $_GET['product_' . $term->term_id]
```

**Changed to:**

```
if( isset( $_POST['product_' . $term->term_id ] ) && $_POST['product_' . $term->term_id]
```